# What is the name of this function? / _

Tags: functions, terminology

I think there is a common name for this function but I can't remember it.
\begin{equation}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 + ax, \text{if } x \leq 0 \\
 0, \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
A plot of this function would be like
this one

[image]

Comment: Maybe you mean the [Heaviside function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)? (Which is different, but does have a name.)

Comment: Does this function have any special properties? The only thing "special" to me is the gap, but if one talks about this gap one usually uses the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) or the [heaviside function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)

Comment: Yes, I am using it for that gap. I am not sure if this function is a particular case of the Heaviside.

Comment: This looks very similar to a [sawtooth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave), but with one pulse (i.e. $\left\{1\ge x>0:x-\operatorname{floor}\left(x\right)\right\}$). For general $a\in\mathbb{R}$, the equation for the function is $\left\{a\ge x>a-1:x-\operatorname{floor}\left(x-a\right)-a\right\}$.

Comment: First name or family name?